# Angular: No provider for component, [multiple Angular HTML elements] is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, frontend, karma-jasmine

I am currently getting the following unit test failures:

`'mat-card' is not a known element (used in the 'ChatCardComponent' component template):`

`'app-card' is not a known element (used in the 'DashboardComponent' component template)`

`R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DashboardComponent -> DashboardComponent]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for DashboardComponent!`

`R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UserService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!`

`'mat-card' is not a known element (used in the 'CardComponent' component template):`

`'app-head-bar' is not a known element (used in the 'HomePageComponent' component template)`

I find this odd as I have declared and imported everything that is allegedly missing from my app.module.ts. I do not have any other module files.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HeadBarComponent} from './head-bar/head-bar.component';
import {DashComponent} from './dash/dash.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DashboardComponent } from './card/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
import { KlausurenCardComponent } from './card/klausuren-card/klausuren-card.component';
import { ChatCardComponent } from './card/chat-card/chat-card.component';
import { HausaufgabenCardComponent } from './card/hausaufgaben-card/hausaufgaben-card.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './user/login-page/login-page.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './card/home-page/home-page.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import {NgOptimizedImage} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeadBarComponent,
        DashComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        CardComponent,
        KlausurenCardComponent,
        ChatCardComponent,
        HausaufgabenCardComponent,
        LoginPageComponent,
        HomePageComponent,
        SettingsComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatIconModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        NgOptimizedImage
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I am trying to run Karma tests for my Angular frontend, I have already tried reinstalling Angular Materials, thinking that the install may have broken, but nothing resulted from this. I'm still getting these errors. Where is the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you import the AppCard and MatCard modules in your test?
If not try adding

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
```

in your test.